Missing ICMP identifier equivalent in ARP protocol and desired arping behavior
Running simultaneously more arping on the same interface and the destination IP address all clients get the responses due missing ICMP identifier equivalent.
First, am I correct that there is no ICMP identifier equivalent in ARP protocol (e.g. UID or just some random value)?
If there is one, how to use it properly?
If not, what would be a correct behavior of arping implementation?
arping from busybox ignore when it gets more responses than replies (sent 2, receive 4):
# busybox arping -c2 -I eth0 192.168.255.1 -w10 & busybox arping -c2 -I eth0 192.168.255.1 -w10 & 
[1] 257782
[2] 257783
ARPING 192.168.255.1 from 192.168.255.133 eth0
ARPING 192.168.255.1 from 192.168.255.133 eth0
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:eb:f6:87:9d:d0] 1.185ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:eb:f6:87:9d:d0] 1.213ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:eb:f6:87:9d:d0] 1.386ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:eb:f6:87:9d:d0] 1.401ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:eb:f6:87:9d:d0] 0.973ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:eb:f6:87:9d:d0] 0.900ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:eb:f6:87:9d:d0] 1.060ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:eb:f6:87:9d:d0] 1.067ms
Sent 2 probe(s) (0 broadcast(s))
Received 4 response(s) (0 request(s), 0 broadcast(s))
Sent 2 probe(s) (0 broadcast(s))
Received 4 response(s) (0 request(s), 0 broadcast(s))
[ ENTER ]
[1]-  Done                    busybox arping -c2 -I eth0 192.168.255.1 -w10
[2]+  Done                    busybox arping -c2 -I eth0 192.168.255.1 -w10

But arping (from iputils) "complains" (set exit code non-zero, since 84ca65c, which is a short fix of 67e070d:):
# ./builddir/arping -c2 -I eth0 192.168.255.1 -w10 & ./builddir/arping -c2 -I eth0 192.168.255.1 -w10 & 
[1] 253703
[2] 253704
ARPING 192.168.255.1 from 192.168.255.133 eth0
ARPING 192.168.255.1 from 192.168.255.133 eth0
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:EB:F6:87:9D:D0]  1.722ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:EB:F6:87:9D:D0]  1.726ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:EB:F6:87:9D:D0]  1.910ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.255.1 [50:EB:F6:87:9D:D0]  1.915ms
Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 2 response(s)
Received 2 response(s)
[ ENTER ]
[1]-  Exit 1                  ./builddir/arping -c2 -I eth0 192.168.255.1 -w10
[2]+  Exit 1                  ./builddir/arping -c2 -I eth0 192.168.255.1 -w10

I wonder if these changes were correct (reported: https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/538) or if the project should restore the old behavior. Does RFC mention something about this problem?

'arping' isn't actually a thing. It's a common term for using an ARP request/probe to check for host availability or presence. The result is binary: there's an ARP reply or there isn't.
And no, there's no identification for which specific ARP request the reply was made (akin to ICMP Echo's Identifier and Sequence Number fields).
The basic premise is: if there's an ARP reply the host is there, regardless of the number of requests. If you require additional information then 'arping' isn't the right thing for you perhaps.
See RFC 826 for details.

Answer from my colleague:
There is indeed no way of linking REQUEST and REPLY together.
The collision problem can be manifested when there are multiple senders e.g. containers or simply backgrounded tasks all sending requests, they may also receive a reply causes request sent by an another instance. It's easily reproducible when one instance sends more requests due lower send interval (using -w):
# arping -I eth0 -c 3 10.10.20.67
ARPING 10.10.20.67 from 10.10.20.33 eth0
Unicast reply from 10.10.20.67 [00:80:C8:7E:71:D4]  11.298ms
Unicast reply from 10.10.20.67 [00:80:C8:E8:1E:FC]  12.077ms
Unicast reply from 10.10.20.67 [00:80:C8:E8:1E:FC]  1.542ms
Unicast reply from 10.10.20.67 [00:80:C8:E8:1E:FC]  1.547ms
Sent 3 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 4 response(s)

(source: https://www.google.com/search?q=ARP+Flux)
Also, the replies may even use different source MAC addresses for the same IP, when the arpinged host has multiple NICs on the same subnet, each NIC may send a reply (see arp_filter and arp_announce sysctl how to influence this), that's why source MAC addresses is not verified.
